# Positioning by length of line-element section using QGIS

Tags: length, position

To indicate a position along a line-element (like a road, or in my case a river) I want to use the chainage of the river (in German: Kilometrierung) rather than regular coordinates.

The chainage of a river is counted from its mouth upstream, so a position at the river would be given by the length from the river mouth along the course of the river to the particular point.

Which calculation / syntax can I use, to generate this datum from a chosen position at the river - say for example in a field survey (field walking) for river restoration measures, where I have a line shape of the river as active layer.

Comment: This use case is known as "Linear Referencing", there are several QGIS plugins offering tool for it. QGIS has also some fonction that you could use (line_locate_point and line_interpolate_point come to mind there could be other ....) Without more info on what you are trying to do it's hard to help more

Comment: I have done this recently.  Do you need kilometer markings or do you have specific marker points?

Comment: I used QGIS - Processing - Toolbox - Points along geometry.  Then I  added a "Name" Field and programmatically added the marker name by: exporting the csv and using "Excel" to add 0.1 Kilometer "Names" to all points.  Then I added the points back to QGIS.